# How to view images of local network from remote interface when using <img src="" />?

Tags: php, html, networking, browser

I have a following network setup:

```
         ___________> [Remote IP] * can access anything from 192.168.1.2.
        |                         * it has a public static ip to access as 8x.8x.2xx.1x
        |
        ^
      [WAN]
        |
     [Router]
        |
        |---[LAN]
        |
   [HTTP WEB SERVER]@192.168.1.2
        |
        |
  --------------------------------------------------- (LAN)
    |             |               |
  [PC1]         [PC2]           [PC3]
  |             |               |
  192.168.1.3   192.168.1.4     192.168.1.5
```

**Case example:**

[OK    ]: PC1, PC2 has image available form 192.168.1.3:7007/picture1.jpeg and 192.168.1.4:7007/picture1.jpeg

[OK    ]: PC3 if i open the site from 192.168.1.2 i can see picture1 and picture2. As my HTML code is:

```
<img src="http://192.168.1.3:7007/picture1.jpeg?1323809545000?1323809546000?1323809547000" class="monitor_realtime" />

<img src="http://192.168.1.4:7007/picture1.jpeg?1323809545000?1323809546000?1323809547000" class="monitor_realtime" />
```

[NOT OK]: But if i now remotely from public location open the page i can not see the pictures.

How can i see pictures when i am opening it remotely (local browsing works)?

Comment: How do you open the website remotely in the first place? Don't you have some public address or dynamic hostname? And how do your `<img>` references look like in the html page source?

Comment: I think his web server is publicly exposed, but the computers aren't. And he is using a local ip address to load images. At least that is the way i read it.

Comment: Search on [Serverfault.SE](http://serverfault.com/) for similar topics. (Search first! But flag your question for moderator attention then, if you want it moved and possibly answered there.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you saying that PC1 and PC2 also both have a Web server running on port 7007? If so, presumably the router does not forward requests to those Web servers. If you plan to access content hosted on a LAN, then the router must know to forward those requests to the relevant server.

**EDIT**: Based on context provided in your comment to m4tt1mus' answer, you'd need to go with the second option. You could set up the router to forward port 81 to port 7007 of PC1 and port 82 to port 7007 of PC2.

Comment: PC1, PC2, PC3, SERVER all has there own :7007/picture1.jpeg. The purpose is to remotely view all pictures. (it works locally always).

Comment: Either you need to host everything on SERVER, or you need to set the router to forward requests to each of the different servers on the LAN. You'd probably achieve this by using different ports for each server. Bear in mind that you'd still need to use the external address for the URLs so that they can be viewed externally, which may stop it working internally (due to loopback issues).

Comment: +1 and ticked for answer. The nice thing you explained is without changing the embedded device port because there i cant do anything its embedded. On other-hand it solves my problem because in the router i can actually do that port mapping. Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

The context of 192.168.1.4 is different depending on if you're on the webserver (local) network or the remote computer. The remote computer would look on its own network (not yours) for that image. **You need to use a public IP address or some other remotely exposed address for the pictures for this to work.** Or you could use some strange service that pulls them from the local network and caches them on the web server or something.

Comment: That strange service could be Apache and `mod_proxy` then; forwarding filtered requests from the publically available webserver to the two internal image servers. Obviously listening on different ports, and or utilizing discernable image paths, and `<base href=>` instead of hardcoded internal IP urls.

Comment: Is it not a HTML or Browser BUG? They missed it in `<img [local] or [wan] interface binding />` ?

Comment: PC1, PC2 is my IPCAmeras, who sends real-time preview's per 3 seconds. (and they are embedded device, i do not have ability to modify the port, its fixed like injection).

Comment: @Google No it isn't a bug in HTML or the img tag. It was never designed to allow you to see things you don't have access to.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem, but I couldn't change the router configuration. So I came up with alternative solution for such cases. Instead of setting the route from one network to another I have changed the way the images are served without changing their location.  My solution is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37293184/loading-image-from-remote-server-in-different-lan).
The code snippets are for my stack (Asp.NET/Nancy/Razor) but the idea is technology agnostic.
In short, you can convert the images "on the fly" to base64 string and serve them embedded in you page from your public server. It works perfect for me with following code (C#):

```
private string convertToBase64(string imageURL)
{
    var request = WebRequest.Create(imageURL);

    using (var response = request.GetResponse())
    {
        using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
        {
            using (Image image = Image.FromStream(stream))
            {
                using (MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    image.Save(m, image.RawFormat);
                    byte[] imageBytes = m.ToArray();
                    string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
                    return string.Format("data:image/png;base64,{0}", base64String);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then converted image is passed to the View as a one of the @Model properties (Base64Image):

```
<img id="photo" src="@Model.Base64Image" title="@Model.Description" />
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12393119)

Comment: @Machavity: Thanks for the lesson. I corrected my answer following your suggestions.